# Overwrite content of before pseudo-element in tailwind css typography plugin

Tags: tailwind-css

I want to customize default behavior of tailwind's `prose` class from typography plugin. Specifically I want to remove backticks from `code::before` and `code::after`.

I've tried the following approach:

`tailwind.config.js`

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

import defaultTheme from 'tailwindcss/defaultTheme'

module.exports = {
  content: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      typography: {
        DEFAULT: {
          css: {
            code: {
              'background-color': '#e5e7eb',
              // before and after are still showing backticks, but should be empty
              '&::before': {
                content: '""',
              },
              '&::after': {
                content: '""',
              },
              'border-radius': '0.25rem',
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
  ],
}
```

Here is the result in Firefox Dev Tools:

[image: dev-tools-screenshot]

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Relevant links:

- [Typography plugin docs: customizing the css](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin#customizing-the-css)
- [Typography plugin on GitHub](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-typography)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The before and after pseudo elements need to be defined like this:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      typography: {
        DEFAULT: {
          css: {
            'code::before': {
              content: 'normal',
            },
            'code::after': {
              content: 'normal',
            },
            code: {
              'background-color': '#e5e7eb',
              'border-radius': '0.25rem',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/typography')],
}
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/1dD9LnWSHW?file=config